# Editing a custom user field onBeforeSave

Tags: plugin-development

When a user saves a front-end form, and has a custom field with a set value, I want to send an email - and set another field on the users profile to indicate a mail has been sent, so that if the form is saved again, another email will not be sent.

To do this I have a small plugin:

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.onSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
        $user = $event->params['user'];
        $consentGiven = craft()->request->getPost('fields.consentGiven', 'no');
        $notificationAlreadySent = $user->notificationAlreadySent;

        if($consentGiven == 'yes' and $notificationAlreadySent != '1') {
            ... SEND EMAIL CODE ...

            // now set the notificationAlreadySent to '1' so we dont get in this conditional next time
                $userModel = new UserModel();

                // why we need to manually read these to write the same values I don't know
                $userModel->id        = $user->id;
                $userModel->username  = $user->username;
                $userModel->firstName = $user->firstName;
                $userModel->lastName  = $user->lastName;
                $userModel->email     = $user->email;

                // update the one field we actually wanted to update in the first place
                $userModel->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
                    'notificationAlreadySent' => '1'
                ));

                // Actually save it
                craft()->users->saveUser($userModel);
        }
    }
});
```

Problem: This ends up in a loop because it's watching the onSaveUser event, and inside that event it's calling saveUser. I figure I actually need the onBeforeSaveUser event, and I need to tweak the value of that field there so that it'll "just work" once it gets to the saveUser action.

That being the case I've tried this instead...

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
        $user = $event->params['user'];
        $consentGiven = craft()->request->getPost('fields.consentGiven', 'no');
        $notificationAlreadySent = $user->notificationAlreadySent;

        if($consentGiven == 'yes' and $notificationAlreadySent != '1') {
            ... SEND EMAIL CODE ...

            // now set the notificationAlreadySent to '1' so we dont get in this conditional next time
                $user->fields['notificationAlreadySent'] = '1';
        }
    }
});
```

New problem: The syntax $user->fields['notificationAlreadySent'] = '1'; doesn't appear to be correct, and I can not work out how to reference that property...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of:

```
$user->fields['notificationAlreadySent'] = '1';
```

Use

```
$user->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
    'notificationAlreadySent' => 1
));
```

Of note: I find this sort of thing extremely hard to research. I know what I want to do (edit the value of a field in an event via the onBefore listener) but documentation on *how* to do that seems non-existent. I keep finding this sort of problem with developing Craft plugins - that unless you know the internals, you're really hard pressed to even articulate what you're wanting to search for in order to find a solution.